# CSS Vertical-alignment of an image inside a div

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I have this div and inside the div is an image, and what I am trying to do is vertically align the image to be centered in the middle and nothing I try seems to work...

```
<div style=" height: 200px; vertical-align: middle; width: 225px;">
<img width="225" src="upload/home5.jpg">
</div>
```

I've also tried this adding a `vertical-align:middle;` to the image as well, but that didn't work.

Anyone got any ideas?

I forgot to mention that I am using some jQuery code and it makes my div `position:absolute;`

this is what my div looks like after it goes through the Jquery

`<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: block; z-index: 4; opacity: 1; width: 225px; height: 200px;">`

and here is the css for the image

```
img {    
    background-color: #eee;
    margin: auto;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use display: table-cell for this on the div. This allows vertical-align attribute to work. No support for IE7. If you need that there are other solutions.

http://jsfiddle.net/5HzpM/

```
div { border: 1px solid gray; display: table-cell;  }
img { vertical-align:middle; }
```

Comment: I edited you're jsfiddle, I am running a jQuery code that makes my divs position absolute, so your solution is not working :(

Comment: @user1193385 - absolutel positioning shouldn't affect this solution. Are you sure you did it correctly? http://jsfiddle.net/5HzpM/10/

Comment: This works now...if I div around the over div and apply your code the second div than it works...thank eh